# How does structure padding work in ESP32's compiler

Tags: c++, struct, arduino, microcontroller, esp32

I was talking with a friend and trying out different structure configurations. And looking at the outputs has me confused as to how the structure is being padded. I'm using wokwi's online esp32 compiler for this. The structure configurations that have me confused are:

```cpp
struct bruh{
  short int aK;
  short int a;
  char cd;
}; 
//Printing the size of this structure gives the output as 6. 
// I would have assumed either 8(padded) or 5(packed). Why?
```

The other example that has me puzzled is:

```cpp
struct bruh{  
    int aK;  
    char cd;  
}; 
//Output is 8. Understandable. 
//Int is 4 bytes, and the extra character gets padded to the next 4 bytes.
```

but!

```cpp
struct bruh{  
    char cd;  
}; 
//Gives me the output as 1. If the example before this one is getting
// padded because of the additional character byte, why isn't this structure 4 bytes?
```

Comment: If you understand the padding of the second example, why don't you understand the padding of the first? Did you consider arrays of such structs? -- Since you mention that the compiler is online, would you mind to add a link to a [mre], please?

Comment: @thebusybee https://wokwi.com/projects/346116480532742738 . 

I can't understand it because (2+2)+(1+) is 6, but (4)+(1+) is 8.
brackets are to indicate memory cells accessed in one clock cycle.

Comment: I'm sure there are instructions that access smaller amounts, too. -- But see the answer below. If it fits, please mark it as accepted. If not, [edit] your question and elaborate on you issues.

Comment: esp32 doesnt have a compiler.   padding is implementation defined, as in each compiler chooses and can to so far as each version or affected by command line options, etc.  for gcc or llvm/clang then it is not just version but also target where it can vary.

Comment: if you are trying to use structs across compile domains, then just dont, there is rarely if ever a good reason to know the size...many abuse this yes...and pay for it later...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Padding is not to bring the size up to the next multiple of 4, it is to ensure every member is always on the correct alignment. Different types have different alignment requirements, and these are all implementation-defined.

You can use the `alignof` operator to look at the alignment of a type.

[Here's one compiler](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd8580cf80d14ff0) reporting what it does with your types

Comment: Got it! size of the structure is always a multiple of the biggest member in the structure